# How to use MemoryMappedViewAccessor properly?

Tags: c#, struct, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

Edit: If you're going to downvote, explain why please. Doesn't help anyone.

I'm really trying to understand how to use memory-mapped files properly, but I'm having some issues. Here's the scenario:

I have some large files, anywhere from 1-10 GB. These are composed of `structs`, all 128 bytes except the very first one of the file.

I need random access to any one of these structs fast, which from what I read is what a memory-mapped file is perfect for. I also need these memory-mapped files to be able to be opened by other processes, but there won't be any writing, just reading of the file.

I am able to determine the byte offset of the exact struct I need to read.

First I tried making the mem-mapped file like so:

```
MemoryMappedFile hFileMapping = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(rampPath, FMode, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rampPath), GetFileLength(rampPath), access);
```

However, other processes couldn't open it. So I found that there was another constructor that took in a `FileStream`. So I changed it to this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(rampPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
MemoryMappedFile hFileMapping = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fs, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rampPath), GetFileLength(rampPath), access, null, HandleInheritability.Inheritable, true);
```

Other processes could open the mem-mapped file now. Then I try making a view of the mapped file:

```
MemoryMappedViewAccessor hFileAccessor = hFileMapping.CreateViewAccessor(0, GetFileLength(rampPath), MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read));
```

This is fine if the files are small, but if they are large I get `out of storage` and memory exceptions.

So I need to map only a portion of the file at one time, but what is the best way to determine if the struct I'm looking for is in the currently mapped view? Do I keep track of the current mapped view's offset and length and see if the offset of the struct is in there? Is there a better way to go about all this?

Comment: If your primary identifier is sequential then you can use a calculation based on the known size and offset. If the page is in memory then great, if not then you have a clear number of offsets that you need to read to get to where you think your record of interest may be. If you can not use a sequential access method then you will have to read your partitions from beginning to end, however, you can build in techniques to increase efficiency like caching your identifiers and the partition offset as you read the structures and other index-'esque' stuff.

Comment: Record by record reads with the ViewAccessor might work for you,  however, larger hops may prove more efficient depending on workload.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "primary identifier is sequential"?

Comment: I mean the structs lay seqeunctially in your file by a value that identifies the struct. For example, StructID -->1-->2-->3-->4. If you know how large your read buffer is and you know the fixed size of the structs then navigation should be somewhat trivial.

Comment: Ohhh right. Okay, going to test it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ross Bush in the OP's comments for the suggestions.

What I did was just make the `ViewAccessor`'s capacity a set amount always. And since I have the byte offset I need, I just ran some calculations to determine if the byte offset was inside the `ViewAccessor` or not. If it wasn't, then change the `ViewAccessor` to a different offset/capacity so the byte offset fell within it.